# Not able to start SOLR service

Tags: solr, lucene, solrcloud

I have installed the solr service on a LINUX environment. Now trying to start the service using the below command

```
service solr start
```

After executing this command, am getting below error from the server

```
Waiting to see Solr listening on port 8080 [-]  Still not seeing Solr listening on 8080 after 30 seconds!
tail: cannot open `/var/solr/logs/solr.log' for reading: No such file or directory
```

I created the solr.log file manually and placed it under the above mentioned path, But as soon, i issue the command "service solr start" . The solr.log file will be renamed and there won't be any new file created with the solr.log. hence the service fails to start. Could anyone let me know how to tackle this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you ensured that the directory and log file are writable by the `solr` user?

Comment: Yes , all users had write access on the directory

Comment: Have you tried starting it like so: ./solr start -p 8080
Based on what I've read, the service command might reset some of your environment variables which may be causing a problem

Comment: No I didn't tried it in that way, am starting using the service directly

Comment: Try starting it as a process (./) and see if that works

Comment: @BinoyDalal as process means could you please explain little am new to this stuff.

Comment: Try to run solr like this `./solr start -p 8080` from the `bin` directory

Comment: @BinoyDalal if  I start like that it will start, but my requirement is to start solr as a service , so even if server is restarted it should automatically  come up with out any manual work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, did you use the procedure provided to install the Solr service page 461

Second, did you set the proper overrides to the environment defaults in a solr.in.sh script (p. 462 of the ref manual). You also need to make sure that the LOG4J_PROPS in the solr.in.sh file points to your log4j.properties file. Also make sure that SOLR_LOGS_DIR is pointing to the correct place.

If all that is correct, then check that the values in your log4j.properties file are set correctly (p. 468 of the ref manual).

You can get the reference manual here: https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/lucene/solr/ref-guide/ if you don't have it already.

I had a tough time getting Solr to run as a service, but in the end I simply wasn't reading carefully enough.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue, and was able to find a hint in the /var/solr/logs/solr-8983-console.log

Originally I had been using Java 8, and Solr was working just fine for me.
When I switched to Java 11, Solr would have the issue you reported.

The log file contained the following:

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Unrecognized VM option 'UseParNewGC'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

I switched back to Java 8 and Solr started just fine.

Comment: This answer could be marked as accepted because this is a real bug appearing with valid solr configurations

Comment: Seconded, @Julien. This worked for me also.